# Ant Design Vue: Modal Component will not work with the Composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, antd, ant-design-vue

I'm using Vue3 with [Ant Design Vue](https://www.antdv.com/components/modal/) and would like create a 'Modal' component that I can reuse throughout the app.

Something very simple like so:

```html
<template>
    <a-button type="primary" @click="showModal">Open</a-button>
    <a-modal v-model="visible" wrap-class-name="full-modal-to-xl">
        <p>Some contents...</p>
        <p>Some contents...</p>
        <p>Some contents...</p>
    </a-modal>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { ref, defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
    setup() {
        const visible = ref(false);

        const showModal = () => {
            visible.value = true;
        };
        return { visible, showModal };
    },
});
</script>
```

But it simply will not work...(no console log, or error).

It does seem to work when you pass `visible` as a prop, but I really do not want to do that. This should work just as well...

What am I missing?

EDIT:
Solution (but not really a solution) Using the [Composition API](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/composition-api-faq.html) is not feasible with Ant it seems.

Comment: `simply will not work` - what should it do? what does it do instead? "Does not work" tells us nothing

Comment: @Bravo Thanks, I added more context and a potential solution

Comment: Oh, right, so whatever this ant design vue thing is, it's not compatible with vue3 - that's a failing of antdv - does it claim to be compatible?

Answer (score 3):

The modal's `v-model` needs to be on its `visible` prop:

```html
<a-modal v-model:visible="visible">
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-ant-design-modal?file=src%2FApp.vue)